# Issue with out system.Array Conversion for solidworks plugin C#

Tags: c#, arrays, add-in, solidworks

I just got thrown into a C# project for solidWorks that I'm not too comfortable with. I need to convert this `out System.Array` to a `string[]`. Then that string is called and converted from `out System.Array` to `out EdmLib.EdmBatchError2[]`.

TLDR: `out System.Array`' to a `string[]`.

Code:

```
private void GetSerialNumberGenerators() 
{
    IEdmSerNoGen7 utility = this.m_vault.CreateUtility(EdmUtility.EdmUtil_SerNoGen) as IEdmSerNoGen7;
    Array ppoRetNames = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string[]), 0);
    utility.GetSerialNumberNames(out ppoRetNames);
    this.comboBoxSerialNumber.DataSource = (object) ppoRetNames;
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'out System.Array' to 'out string[]'

Comment: Why you use `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string[]), 0);` at all? You don't know how to declare arrays? It's simple: `string[] ppoRetNames;`. Since `GetSerialNumberNames` will initialize it(`out`-parameter) you don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple as

```
string[] ppoRetNames;
GetSerialNumberNames(out ppoRetNames);
```

This is the way to declare a `string[]`. Don't initialize it yourself because `GetSerialNumberNames` will do it ([`out`-parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)). No need to use `Array.CreateInstance`.

Apart from that you are creating a jagged array because you pass `typeof(string[])` not `typeof(string)`. You need a one dimensional array so this would be correct:

```
Array someArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), 0);
string[] ppoRetNames = (string[])someArray;  // so a cast is what was missing
```

Answer (score 0):

GetSerialNumberNames returns System.Array of type [EdmBatchError2](http://help.solidworks.com/2018/English/api/epdmapi/EPDM.Interop.epdm~EPDM.Interop.epdm.EdmBatchError2.html), which is a structure of 4 ints, so I don't know how that would cast to a string[] in a usable sense.  Here is what I do:

```
utility.GetSerialNumberNames(out Array ppoRetNames);
foreach(EdmBatchError2 batchError in ppoRetNames) {
    // construct error message with below variables for each error
    //batchError.mlFileID;
    //batchError.mlFolderID;
    //batchError.mlVariableID;
    //batchError.mlErrorCode;
}
```